# Gradle build failed: Could not determine Java version

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I have been trying to remedy this for days and have come to no avail so I will get straight to the point.

I am trying to run a VR demo using Unity and when I "build and run" the project I get an error stating:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not determine java version from '9.0.4'.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>     ]
>     stdout[
>
> ]
>   exit code: 1
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
>   UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
>   Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
>   UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

I have already tried the "replace the tool folder" fix and it worked to a certain extent however when I get to this point it does not work.

Comment: Try to use java 8 instead of java 9